# Pushforward of sheafs is not exact

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am very new to algebraic geometry. At the point of studying pushforward of a sheas I am wondering that does it is an exact function? Many resources (like MSE questions) telling that it is left exact but not right but not providing any concrete examle. But the pushforward under inclusion of a closed set is exact and the same for open set is not true.

Can someone give an explicit example of a this non exactness phenomena on inclusion of open sets?

I was trying with skyscraper
Sheaf and constant sheaf, their direct product etc. but I did not get any proper example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The most important example of a pushforward is pushforward to a point (specifically the spectrum of the ground field along the structure morphism), which is the same thing as the global section functor. Do you know examples of why *this* is not exact?

Comment: @TabesBridges yes I know that global section functor is not exact. One can tale the exponential exact sequence on punctured complex plane. But I want an example where exact sequence of sheaves on an open set becomes non exact after pushforward.

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $i \colon U \to \mathbb{A}^2$ be the embedding of the complement of the origin. Consider the sequence
$$
0 \to 
\mathcal{O}_U \stackrel{(-y,x)} \to 
\mathcal{O}_U \oplus \mathcal{O}_U \stackrel{(x,y)} \to
\mathcal{O}_U \to 0. 
$$
It is exact, because $x$ and $y$ have no common zeros on $U$, hence form a regular sequence. On the other hand, $i_*\mathcal{O}_U \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2}$ (by the Hartog's theorem}, hence the pushforward of the sequence looks like
$$
0 \to 
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2} \stackrel{(-y,x)} \to 
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2} \stackrel{(x,y)} \to
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2} \to 0,
$$
and it is no longer exact because now $x$ and $y$ have common zero at the origin.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I am beginar in these, can tell what the notation in the morphism (-y,x) or (x,y) is?     
Is there any easy example which does not use Hartog’s theorem?

Comment: Sure, $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates on the affine plane, hence functions, and the corresponding morphisms are the multiplications by these functions. I am not sure that easier example exists --- the embedding morphism must be non-affine, and the embedding of the punctured plane is the simplest non-affine morphism. You can avoid using Hartog's Theorem by computing the pushforward with a simple affine covering of the punctured plane.

Comment: if we replace $\mathbb{A}^2$ by $\mathbb{C}^2$  and take the sheaf of holomorphic functions then can we define some morphisms for which the same thing as in your example holds?

Comment: Why having common zero at origin makes the latter sequence non exact?

Comment: I guess Hartog's theorem is also true for holomorphic functions, so yes, the same example works in this setting. The second morphism vanishes at the point where $x = y = 0$, hence it is not surjective, and the sequence is not exact.